# Spark SQL search inside an array for a struct

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

My data structure is defined approximately as follows:

```
schema = StructType([
# ... fields skipped
StructField("extra_features", 
ArrayType(StructType([
    StructField("key", StringType(), False),
    StructField("value", StringType(), True)
])), nullable = False)],
)
```

Now, I'd like to search for entries in a data frame where a struct `{"key": "somekey", "value": "somevalue"}` exists in the array column. How do I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Spark has a function [`array_contains`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.array_contains) that can be used to check the contents of an `ArrayType` column, but unfortunately it doesn't seem like it can handle arrays of complex types. It is possible to do it with a UDF (*User Defined Function*) however:

```
from pyspark.sql.types import *
from pyspark.sql import Row
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

schema = StructType([StructField("extra_features", ArrayType(StructType([
    StructField("key", StringType(), False),
    StructField("value", StringType(), True)])),
    False)])

df = spark.createDataFrame([
    Row([{'key': 'a', 'value': '1'}]),
    Row([{'key': 'b', 'value': '2'}])], schema)

# UDF to check whether {'key': 'a', 'value': '1'} is in an array
# The actual data of a (nested) StructType value is a Row
contains_keyval = F.udf(lambda extra_features: Row(key='a', value='1') in extra_features, BooleanType())

df.where(contains_keyval(df.extra_features)).collect()
```

This results in:

```
[Row(extra_features=[Row(key=u'a', value=u'1')])]
```

You can also use the UDF to add another column that indicates whether the key-value pair is present:

```
df.withColumn('contains_it', contains_keyval(df.extra_features)).collect()
```

results in:

```
[Row(extra_features=[Row(key=u'a', value=u'1')], contains_it=True),
 Row(extra_features=[Row(key=u'b', value=u'2')], contains_it=False)]
```

Answer (score 1):

Since Spark 2.4.0 **you can use the functions [exist](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#exists)**.

Example with SparkSQL:

```
SELECT
    EXISTS
    (
        ARRAY(named_struct("key": "a", "value": "1"), named_struct("key": "b", "value": "2")),
        x -> x = named_struct("key": "a", "value": "1")
    )
```

Example with PySpark:

```
df.filter('exists(extra_features, x -> x = named_struct("key": "a", "value": "1"))')
```

Note that **not all the functions to manipulate arrays start with array_***.
Ex: [exist](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#exists), [filter](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#filter), [size](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#size), ...