# Extracting a field from array with a structure inside it in Spark Sql

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, hiveql

I have a table with one field called xyz as array which has a struct inside it like below

```
array<struct<site_id:int,time:string,abc:array>>
```

the values in this field is below

```
[{"site_id":3,"time":"2020-07-26 05:48:21","abc":[{"to_bidder":"val1"}]]
```

This is a sample representation , in reality this field has a lot of fields ,my quest is to extract corresponding to key "abc" without using inline and explode if possible to not have memory errors in Spark-Sql

I tried array_contains(xyz,"abc") , but it gave me an error

```
data type mismatch: Arguments must be an array followed by a value of same type as the array members;
```

I tried @Srinivas code ,but it gave me tyoe mismatch error

```
cannot resolve 'flatten(k.`xyz`.`abc`)' due to data type mismatch: The argument should be an array of arrays, but 'k.`xyz`.`abc`' is of array<map<string,string>>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Spark SQL search inside an array for a struct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42234274/spark-sql-search-inside-an-array-for-a-struct)

Comment: I am looking for Spark-Sql solution actually , not a scala or pyspark solution

Comment: abc is not array type .. its ```struct``` or ```map``` type. check once

Comment: below solution will work - if your data is in this - [{"site_id":3,"time":"2020-07-26 05:48:21","abc":[{"to_bidder":"val1"}]] this data actually matches your schema ``` array<struct<site_id:int,time:string,abc:array>> ```

Comment: Check again, I have updated solution as per your sample data not schema.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

function `array_contains` returns only `true` or `false`.

To access specific column inside array of struct, use `array_column.field_name` it will return `array of field values`

Check below code.

```
df
.withColumn("column",$"data.abc") // Extract Column value
.withColumn("column_with_array_contains",array_contains($"data.abc","val1")) // It will return true or false.
.withColumn("column_with_concat",concat_ws(",",$"data.abc")) // It will concat column values.
.show(false)


// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

+--------------------------------+------+--------------------------+------------------+
|data                            |column|column_with_array_contains|column_with_concat|
+--------------------------------+------+--------------------------+------------------+
|[[val1, 3, 2020-07-26 05:48:21]]|[val1]|true                      |val1              |
+--------------------------------+------+--------------------------+------------------+
```

**Spark SQL**

```
scala> spark.sql("select data, data.abc as column,array_contains(data.abc,'val1') as column_with_array_contains,concat_ws(',',data.abc) as column_with_concat  from sample").show(false)
+--------------------------------+------+--------------------------+------------------+
|data                            |column|column_with_array_contains|column_with_concat|
+--------------------------------+------+--------------------------+------------------+
|[[val1, 3, 2020-07-26 05:48:21]]|[val1]|true                      |val1              |
+--------------------------------+------+--------------------------+------------------+
```

**Updated** - Spark Version - 3.0.0, Below code might not work lower versions of spark. Check once.

```
scala> spark.sql("select data, flatten(data.abc)['to_bidder'] as column, array_contains(flatten(data.abc)['to_bidder'],'val1') as column_with_array_contains,concat_ws(',',flatten(data.abc).to_bidder) as column_with_concat from sample").show(false)
+------------------------------------+------+--------------------------+------------------+
|data                                |column|column_with_array_contains|column_with_concat|
+------------------------------------+------+--------------------------+------------------+
|[[[[val1]], 3, 2020-07-26 05:48:21]]|[val1]|true                      |val1              |
+------------------------------------+------+--------------------------+------------------+
```

**Update-2** - Below solution will work only if your schema & data matches with sample data & sample schema.

**Sample Data**

```
 [{"site_id":3,"time":"2020-07-26 05:48:21","abc":{"to_bidder":"val1"}]
```

**Sample Schema**

```
array<struct<site_id:int,time:string,abc:struct<to_bidder:string>>>
```

```
root
 |-- data: array (nullable = false)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = false)
 |    |    |-- abc: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- to_bidder: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- site_id: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- time: string (nullable = true)
 
scala> spark.sql("select data, data.abc.to_bidder as column, array_contains(data.abc.to_bidder,'val1') as column_with_array_contains,concat_ws(',',data.abc.to_bidder) as column_with_concat from samplea").show(false)
+----------------------------------+------+--------------------------+------------------+
|data                              |column|column_with_array_contains|column_with_concat|
+----------------------------------+------+--------------------------+------------------+
|[[[val1], 3, 2020-07-26 05:48:21]]|[val1]|true                      |val1              |
+----------------------------------+------+--------------------------+------------------+
```

Comment: I only have access to spark-sql , the code which you have written does it work in sql as well ?

Comment: Yes, It will work, check updated code. Please upvote or accept if it helps .. :)

Comment: Hey Srinivas , this is pretty close , my use case abc  is an  array type inside the column xyz , is it possible to still extract from it ?

Comment: spark version ??

Comment: sql version please , dont have spark interface at work

Comment: You might know version of underling spark version ??

Comment: It is spark 2.1

Comment: Check code I have updated, Please don't update existing question, instead raise as new question.

Comment: Hey Srinivas , sorry did not check the comment before editing question , but I got an error still , is there anything you can suggest on this ?

Comment: Last updated solution will work only if your spark supports higher order functions.. means..spark version 2.4+

Comment: can something work with [{"site_id":3,"time":"2020-07-26 05:48:21","abc":[{"to_bidder":"val1"}]] sample data as well

Comment: check code inside ```update``` & It will only work on spark 2.4+ version. lower version I am not sure.. you may need to use ```explode``` or ```lateral view explode``` functions.

Answer (score 0):

It should be `array_contains($col_name.{struct_field},{value})`.

In your case it should be `array_contains(functions.col("xyz.abc"),"value")`

FYI: value has to match the struct_field type, else it'll throw an error.